# The Target Page URL for the navigation Term will not be updated incase the old URL contain [ or ]

Tags: 2013, development, administration, managed-navigation, enterprise-wiki

I am working on a sharepoint enterprise server 2013, and i have the following:-

1. Enterprise wiki site collection , where i have enabled friendly url for my wiki pages inside the Site Navigation settings.
2. now i added a new wiki page which have this name "`Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module]`"
3. where the wiki page got the following values:-

   - Page name= `Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module].aspx`
   - Page title= `Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module]`
   - Navigation Term = `Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module]`
   - Target page for the navigation term= `~sitecollection/Pages/Steps to add new item inside the ERP %5BMain Module%5D.aspx`
4. now i edit the wiki page and i change its name from "`Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module]`" to "`Steps to add new item inside the ERP (Main Module)`", mainly I replace `[]` with `()`,where i got these new values:-

   - Page name =  `Steps to add new item inside the ERP (Main Module).aspx`
   - Page title = `Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module]`
   - Navigation Term =`Steps to add new item inside the ERP [Main Module]`
   - Target page for the navigation term= `~sitecollection/Pages/Steps to add new item inside the ERP %5BMain Module%5D.aspx`

Now i know that updating a wiki page name will not automatically change the Page Title and the Term Name which is fine.

But the problem `in my case is that since the Page name contain these 2 characters` [  ] then when i changed the wiki page name the Target page for the navigation term will not be updated, and it will keep referencing the old url ( `~sitecollection/Pages/Steps to add new item inside the ERP %5BMain Module%5D.aspx` in my case) which no longer exists... keeping in mind that if i add a new wiki page that do not have `[ ]` inside its name then the problem will not happen ,, so seems for a reason or another using `[` or `]` inside the wiki page name while having friendly url enabled will cause the issue..

so can anyone adivce what is going on !!

here is the Target page URL i am talking about, which can be accessed from "Site Settings" >> "Term Store Management"..
[image]

where in normal cases updating the wiki page name, will automatically update the target page url for the navigation term,, but seems when the original wiki page name contain `[` or `]` the target page url will not get updated when changing the associated page name !!